# How do I turn off CSRF protection in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf

The CSRF prevention built in to Rails is causing some problems for some automated load testing we are doing, and I want to turn it off for the duration of the process. How do I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I love simple questions with clear answers.

```
#I go in application.rb
self.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

If you want to do this for testing only you can move that into one of the environment files (obviously, you'll be touching `Application` then rather than `self`).  You could also write something like:

```
#I still go in application.rb
self.allow_forgery_protection = false unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
```

See [here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/9/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-better-cross-site-request-forging-prevention) for details.  (Continuing Rails' wonderful tradition of having documentation of core features in 2 year old blog posts, which were distilled from commit logs.)

Comment: or `self.allow_forgery_protection = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production" ` for short

Comment: got the following error - `/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:196:in `method_missing': undefined method `allow_forgery_protection=' for FertilityApp::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
`

Comment: @VipinVerma Sorry it's 7 years too late, but - application_controller.rb, not application.rb...

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3, remove the `protect_from_forgery` command in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`